# Webinterface for configuring SVN access in mod_dav_svn?

Tags: svn, configuration, mod-dav-svn

we have several team members that would like to edit the AuthzSVNAccessFile for Apache2+mod_dav_svn from time to time (we have many students here which get access and later leave again). The admins are not happy if everybody can edit the config file.

Is there any webinterface module that could be made accessible for those team members on which people can add/remove access to repositories?

Thanks!

Comment: you could try to interface it to LDAP, I haven't done that though (still on my TODO)

Comment: You can use LDAP for the authentication part. However you can't use LDAP for anything that SVNAuthAccessFile buys you (groups, aliases, and path-based access control) unless you buy one of the commercial implementations of SVN. Strange shortcoming really.